# Comparing const char to a string

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, constants

I have an issue comparing a const char to a string... If I use Com_Printf ("%s", value);
It returns what I want (0.3c), but how can I convert value to a string and compare that to 0.3c? This is what I have:

```
value = SearchInfostring(msg, "shortversion");
if (value != "0.3c")
{
    Com_Printf (MSG_WARNING,
            Com_Printf (MSG_WARNING,
                "> WARNING: Value: Should be 0.3c, is:  %s \n",
                value);
//Run stuff
}
```

That returns:
WARNING: Value: Should be 0.3c, is:  0.3c

Comment: Show more code. Where is value declared?

Comment: I assume `value` is `std::string` as you wrote. Are you sure there are no trailing/leading spaces in `value`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If value is of type const char*, expression

```
value != "0.3c"
```

is comparing two pointers (addresses), not strings. You want to compare string and a string literal so can use `strcmp`:

```
if(strcmp(value, "0.3c"))
{
   // strings are not equal
}
else
{
   // strings are equal
}
```

Bear in mind that preferred string type in C++ is `std::string`.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Note that if `value` was of type `std::string` the code you posted would be working as you expected (as chris posted in his answer).

Answer (score 3):

Use an `std::string` for `value`.

```
std::string value = SearchInfoString(msg, "shortversion");
```

Then, you can compare it normally. If you cannot use a string at all for whatever reason (the return value can be converted), use `strcmp`.

```
if (strcmp (value, "0.3c") != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `SearchInfoString` returns a `char *`, based on the way you use it with `Com_Printf`.  Therefore you can just use `strcmp()` to compare `value` to `"0.3c"`.  For example:

```
if (strcmp(value, "0.3c") != 0)
{
    // Print warning
}
```